# carrierwave uploader validates :presence => true not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

**model/songs.rb**

```
require 'file_size_validator'  
  class Song < ActiveRecord::Base  
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader  
    validates :attachment, :presence => true, 
        :file_size => {:maximum => 2.megabytes.to_i}  
  end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<div class="well">  
 <%= form_for @song, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :attachment %>
  <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>  
</div>
```

when I submit empty form or form without file selection it gives error as :-

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing at /songs

param is missing or the value is empty: songs  


actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb  

    182   def require(key)

    183     self[key].presence || raise(ParameterMissing.new(key))

    184   end
```

I'm wondering why **ActiveRecords::Base validates :presence => true** not working.
(new bie to rials)

songs_controller.rb

```
require 'zip'
require 'taglib'  
class SongsController < ApplicationController  
  respond_to :html, :js  

  def index  
    session[:ids] = nil
    @songs = Song.where("song_name IS NOT NULL AND song_path IS NOT NULL").page(1).per(5)
  end  
  def new
    @song = Song.new
    @songs = Song.find(session[:ids]) if !session[:ids].nil?
  end  
  def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)  

    if @song.save
    puts @song.errors.messages
    zip_file_path = Pathname.new(@song.attachment.current_path)
    destination_path = zip_file_path.dirname

    unzip(zip_file_path, destination_path, true) if zip_file_path.extname == ".zip"
    session[:ids] = Array.new
    Dir.glob("#{destination_path}" + '/*') do |music_files|

      if %w(.mp3 .wav .aac .wma .m4a).include? File.extname(music_files)

        song_details = extract_music_metadata(music_files)
        if !song_details.nil?
          @song = Song.new(song_details)
          session[:ids].push(@song.id) if @song.save
        end

      else
        File.delete(music_files)
    end
   end
    redirect_to new_song_url, notice: "The contents of zip files are listed below !!!"
  else
    render "new"
  end  
end  

def edit
  @song = Song.find(params[:id])
end  

def update
  @songs = Song.where("song_name IS NOT NULL AND song_path IS NOT NULL").page(1).per(5)
  @song = Song.find(params[:id])
  @song.update_attributes(song_params)
  if !session[:ids].nil?
    @songs = Song.find(session[:ids])
  end
end  

def delete
  @song = Song.find(params[:id])
end  

def destroy
  @songs = Song.where("song_name IS NOT NULL AND song_path IS NOT NULL").page(1).per(5)
  @song = Song.find(params[:id])
  @song.destroy
  File.delete(@song.song_path)
    if !session[:ids].nil?
    @songs = Song.find(session[:ids])
  end
end  

private

def song_params
  params.require(:song).permit(:attachment, :title, :artist, :album, :year, :track,  
                               :genre, :comment)
end  

# extract contents of a zip file
def unzip(zip, unzip_dir, remove_after = false)
  Zip::File.open(zip) do |zip_file|
    zip_file.each do |f|
      f_path=File.join(unzip_dir, f.name)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
      a = zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
    end
  end
  FileUtils.rm(zip) if remove_after
end  

def extract_music_metadata(music_files)
  TagLib::FileRef.open(music_files) do |fileref|
            unless fileref.null?
              tag = fileref.tag 
              song_details =  {
                              song_name: File.basename(music_files),
                              song_path: music_files, 
                              title: tag.title,
                              artist: tag.artist,
                              album: tag.album,
                              year: tag.year,
                              track: tag.track,
                              genre: tag.genre,
                              comment: tag.comment
                              }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Error from console is:

Started POST "/songs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-16 11:45:10 +0545
Processing by SongsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oLgt6szICw1/4FIiP4dQk2IGSPqQb3l7roS0E1l7ovk=", "commit"=>"Upload"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: song:

Comment: when you give file name is it working fine saving into db? or any errors ?

Comment: which gem you are using for file uploading

Comment: all is working fine, but when I submit empty form params[:song] is not being set, I'm unable to figure out the problem, I'm using carrierwave gem for uploading and custom file_size_validator for carrierwave from git.

Comment: I think ur code is wrong the url you specified is to new action which is unacceptable by rails.